# Get class static member function address in lldb during debugging: Interpreter couldn't resolve a value during execution

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

During debugging in lldb I can get the address of global function without any problems. For instance, I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void globalDoWork()
{
    std::cout << "Global do work call\n";
}

struct Dummy
{
    static void doWork()
    {
        std::cout << "Do work call\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    globalDoWork();
    Dummy::doWork();

    std::cout << "global: " << (void*)&(globalDoWork) << "\n";
    std::cout << "static: " << (void*)&(Dummy::doWork) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

After build executable I run this program under lldb:

```
Process 10759 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x00000001000011a7 ex43`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbff8f0) at ex43.cpp:21:15
   18       globalDoWork();
   19       Dummy::doWork();
   20
-> 21       std::cout << "global: " << (void*)&(globalDoWork) << "\n";
   22       std::cout << "static: " << (void*)&(Dummy::doWork) << "\n";
   23
   24       return 0;
Target 0: (ex43) stopped.
(lldb) p globalDoWork
(void (*)()) $0 = 0x0000000100001100 (ex43`globalDoWork() at ex43.cpp:4)
(lldb) next
global: 0x100001100
```

And get the address, but I can not the same action with class static member function:

```
static: 0x100001220
Process 10765 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001208 ex43`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbff8f0) at ex43.cpp:24:5
   21       std::cout << "global: " << (void*)&(globalDoWork) << "\n";
   22       std::cout << "static: " << (void*)&(Dummy::doWork) << "\n";
   23
-> 24       return 0;
   25   }
Target 0: (ex43) stopped.
(lldb) p Dummy::doWork
error: supposed to interpret, but failed: Interpreter couldn't resolve a value during execution
(lldb) p (void*)&(Dummy::doWork)
error: supposed to interpret, but failed: Interpreter couldn't resolve a value during execution
```

What's the problem? How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  Calling the function works:

```
(lldb) expr Dummy::doWork()
Do work call
```

But we aren't getting the value of the static method as a function pointer out correctly.  Please file a bug about this with http://bugs.llvm.org.

Note, lldb does have simpler ways of finding the address of a symbol, if that's all you wanted to do.  That's the job of the `image lookup` command:

```
(lldb) image lookup -n Dummy::doWork
1 match found in /tmp/dowork:
        Address: dowork[0x0000000100001100] (dowork.__TEXT.__text + 304)
        Summary: dowork`Dummy::doWork() at dowork.cpp:11
```